# Yii2 migration with fk

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii2, migration

i`m very new in Yii2 framework. I start to learn this ...
Now i try to make 2 tables with FK but i cant understand it. I will happy if anyone can say me how must look the table with FK.

Migration one:

```
 public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('portfolio', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'project_name'          => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'main_image'            => $this->string(),
        'galery'                => $this->string(),
        'link_to_live_project'  => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'short_description'     => $this->string(),
        'full_description'      => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'date_released'         => $this->string(),
        'technologies'          => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'created_at'            => $this->dateTime(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function down()
{
    $this->dropTable('portfolio');
}
```

Second migration:

```
 public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('gallery_to_portfolio', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function down()
{
    $this->dropTable('gallery_to_portfolio');
}
```

I wanna make fk in second migration.

Answer (score 2):

Your code for the second migration up function should look something like the following:

```
 $this->createTable('gallery_to_portfolio', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'portfolioId' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        ... other fields ...
    ]);

$this->addForeignKey('fk-gallery_to_portfolio-portfolio','gallery_to_portfolio','portfolioId','portfolio','id','cascade');
```

Comment: Tnx you so much, sir !